# How to mask infected area from the healthy area?

Tags: python, opencv

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img =  cv2.imread('AFTER_5746.png')
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# find the green color 
mask_green = cv2.inRange(hsv, (36,0,0), (86,255,255))
# find the brown color
mask_brown = cv2.inRange(hsv, (90, 60, 20), (30, 255, 200))
# find the yellow color in the leaf
mask_yellow = cv2.inRange(hsv, (14, 39, 64), (40, 255, 255))

# find any of the three colors(green or brown or yellow) in the image
mask = cv2.bitwise_or(mask_green, mask_brown)
mask = cv2.bitwise_or(mask, mask_yellow)

# Bitwise-AND mask and original image
res = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img, mask= mask)

cv2.imshow("original", img)
cv2.imshow("final image", res)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

i use this image segmentation using HSV colormap but the brown area always go missing in the extracted leaf image as shown here:

[image]

how to make the mask_brown visible?
[image: Original Image]

Comment: What happens if you `imshow` the `mask_brown` array? Do you see the brown portion of the image? I can't reproduce the code because you didn't post the original input.

Comment: @stateMachine i have updated the original image. if imshow the mask_brown only show some tiny spot.

Comment: Your mask brown is black. So you need to change your values for the lower and upper threshold color values for brown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your brown mask is empty (no white). How did you get your values for brown? They are not inclusive of brown in OpenCV HSV. Your brown is at the hue=0/180 wrap-around transition. OpenCV inRange() does not seem to like specifying 160 to 20 as lower and upper, respectfully (without separating into two browns, one from 160 to 180 and the other from 0 to 20). So I just gave it 0 to 180 to cover the range. Don't go too high in Value (V) or you will start including the sky.

Here is a selection of colors for the brown that seems to work for me in Python/OpenCV.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img =  cv2.imread('AFTER_5746.png')
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# find the green color 
mask_green = cv2.inRange(hsv, (36,0,0), (86,255,255))
# find the brown color
mask_brown = cv2.inRange(hsv, (0, 0, 0), (180, 255, 160))
# find the yellow color in the leaf
mask_yellow = cv2.inRange(hsv, (14, 39, 64), (40, 255, 255))

# find any of the three colors(green or brown or yellow) in the image
mask = cv2.bitwise_or(mask_green, mask_brown)
mask = cv2.bitwise_or(mask, mask_yellow)

# Bitwise-AND mask and original image
res = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img, mask= mask)

cv2.imshow("original", img)
cv2.imshow("mask_green", mask_green)
cv2.imshow("mask_brown", mask_brown)
cv2.imshow("mask_yellow", mask_yellow)
cv2.imshow("mask", mask)
cv2.imshow("final image", res)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

I assume this is what you want.